# Updating/replacing CoreData sqlite file in app

Tags: xcode, sqlite, core-data

My app currently have this sqlite file (lets name it v1)
What i want to do is that when i activate a IBAction , it will automatically delete the current file (v1) and retrieve values from webservice and store inside a new file (v2) and the application will then use the new sqlite file (v2)

any idea on how to implement?

my current code is here:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"test.sqlite"]];
NSLog(@"%@",storeUrl);


NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
     NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

return persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

}

Answer (score 5):

You can:

1. download the new database from the server
2. reset the whole Core Data context (store coordinator, managed object contexts, managed objects)
3. replace the old database with the new one
4. ask the UI to refresh to display the newest content: the Core Data context should reload lazily

But this approach is quite dangerous, as you'd have to make sure every Core Data object in your app can be reset. Also, replacing the database should happen just after resetting the context, to avoid a race condition. If you have threads / blocks accessing Core Data this is even more difficult.

A better approach may be to update the database records by downloading a JSON file that contains the new database's contents, delete the old records, and insert the new ones. This also makes sure that you can update your Core Data schema in a future version of the app without breaking your content updating process. And by using the [`NSFetchResultsController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, your table views or other UI elements may even update automatically with a nice animation as your database gets updated.

If you care about bandwidth, I use [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers) which are way more compact than any JSON or even sqlite file would be, and quite easy to use.

Comment: ndfred I am currently facing the same issue. I will try your steps 1-4, thank you for the answer. Deleting or updating the database is a good approach but not when you have a large database. When dealing with thousands of record and relationships you will find that this can be very slow. When dealing with large databases from my experience is to replace the db.